# Change the placement position for an existing server in YugabyteDB cluster

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

If a master or tserver is relocated, is it just enough to update its flagfile (or cmd flags) upon the next start to make the rest of the cluster-aware of the relocation?  I just have a server that is labeled wrong in placement tags.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in this case you can update the `--placement_cloud/region/zone` tags for sure.

Also, these flags only matter if you have run the `yb-admin modify_placement_info` command to specify what data placement policy you want.